# Coq - (a \/ b \/ c) = ((a \/ b) \/ c)

Tags: coq

I'm working with semirings, and in order to prove that some structures are actual semirings, I have to prove that they respect some properties, such as associativity.

For the semiring `(Bool, \/, /\, False, True)`, can I prove the following statement ?

`forall a b c : Prop, (a \/ b \/ c) = ((a \/ b) \/ c)`

My problem is in the equality between the two members of the expression. I would have prefered a `<->` instead of the `=`, but my definition of semirings only uses `=`.

Is it still provable ? Or do I have to adapt the definition of my semiring for the particular cases of "propositional-logic-based" semirings ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely provable, for example, by case analysis. I think, you have a problem doing this because you formulated theorem incorrectly. a b and c should be Bool not Prop.

In case of Prop it's provable via reflexivity tactics (if / is left associative).

Comment: Ok thanks, I solved the problem proving `a || (b || c) = a || b || c` instead (which requires Coq.Bool.Bool).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Coq, but that is clearly intuitionistically provable, so there has to be a way to get it done.

Comment: The equivalence of the two statements is intuitionistically provable, I wouldn't bet on the equality though...

Comment: Why?  Equivalence is an equivalence relation on propositions.  The only difference between (<-> and =) is context in a language and syntax, not domain or extension.  And the OP got it done.

Comment: Indeed, the equality is not provable in Coq without additional axioms, even though it should be possible to validate this principle, known as propositional extensionality, in some models. Equality is Coq is very tied to conversion, whereas logical equivalence is more semantic.